Could thermal or quantum fluctuations in the far future ionize matter?
Consider a linearly expanding universe that expands essentially forever
In the very far future, would it be possible for quantum or thermal fluctuations to ionize atoms separating electrons from atoms (even if that would have a very low probability of occurring)?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Yes, this is a consequence of the Herzfeld "paradox", first noted in 1912. The partition function for a sole hydrogen atom is not well behaved, diverging when one takes the infinite number of states of unbound electrons into account. The standard explanation for why hydrogen does not do this is that the presence of other matter causes screening and boundary effects that stop this from happening. Basically, if you assume the free electron is only allowed to move in a finite box, then the ionization does not happen.
But in the far future the expansion of the universe (and decay of black holes) is likely to leave atoms totally isolated within their horizon. As long as temperature is positive (due to the de Sitter temperature due to accelerating expansion) the probability of ionization is finite and will eventually happen.

Thank you @AndersSandberg but I was actually asking about the case of a linearly expanding universe (without acceleration) as it says in OP. In principle it would seem that is not possible, but are there any caveats, exceptions or subtleties? For example, perhaps ionization of all matter in the universe is impossible in those cases, but what about at a local level? Or, if the universe keeps expanding with acceleration and then at some point in the future the cosmological constant vanishes (so it keeps expanding but linearly), could it modify the conditions so that matter ionizes?

@vengaq - I think a linearly expanding universe still gets this situation. The temperature falls like 1/t, but the important issue is that matter gets separated enough. There is a basic argument that since free energy E-TS tends to be minimized, if the entropy factor S can grow faster than T declines then eventually the second term dominates over the binding energy of bound systems.

And if it would ionize would it take much more time than in the case of an expanding universe with acceleration? @AndersSandberg

@vengaq - Accelerating universes have a temperature that declines as T1 exp(-t/H)+T0 where T0 is the de Sitter temperature and T1 current temperature, while linear expansion goes as T1/t. So they will eventually be colder, and hence ionize less quickly. Since this will anyway happen after final black hole decay in 10^100 years, much longer than 1/H, linear universes will be colder than accelerating ones and have slower ionization,  Not that it matters much, since there cannot be any timekeeping systems in such late universes.
